# regex (regular expression): parse the optional end of the string if it exists

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

Please help me to find the end of the string and parse it.

I have the string like this "Some words" and "Some another words||MyTag". Please help me with regex to check any of this strings. But in the second case please extract "MyTag". So please make two groups: "Some words" or "Some another words" and MyTag or empty string.

I tried "^([\W\w]+)(?:||(.*))?" but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 capture groups:

```
^(.+?)(?:\|\|(.+))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1** Match any character except newlines as least as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\|\|(.+)` Match `||` and capture 1+ chars in group 2
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

If the second part is not present, then there will be no group 2 value.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QMaiP/1)

You might also consider to split on `||`

---

Another option without a non greedy dot is to not allow matching `|`, only when it is not directly followed by `|` using a negative lookahead.

```
^([^\r\n|]*(?:\|(?!\|)[^\r\n|]*)*)(?:\|\|(.+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nskcub/1)

Comment: Thank you. The previous answer is the best. Thank you, my hero!))